# Is Norway a rentier and resource-dependent country?

Tags: election, international-relations, economy, voting, democracy

I have been reading a lot on the rentier state literature and have noticed that papers published in the last two decades focus on the typical rentier cases such as Saudi Arabia or Venezuela. However, older literature used to mention Norway as an example, which was confusing to me because I always thought of rentier states as non-democratic countries that are resource-dependent, so I decided to research basic statistics about Norway that are often used to assess whether a country is a rentier state or not, and I was surprised by the descriptive characteristics of Norway.

First, one-third of citizens [remain](https://www.oecd.org/gov/gov-at-a-glance-2021-norway.pdf) employed by the Gov't, oil currently [represents](https://www.norskpetroleum.no/en/economy/governments-revenues/) 64% of total exports, 49% of total government revenues, 33% of its GDP, and the oil sector employs around 19% of residents in the country. If we apply the technical definition in the rentier literature, any country that relies on a natural resource for 40% or more of its government revenues is likely a rentier country.

Perhaps there is no rentier mentality amongst citizens in the same magnitude as Venezuela but surprised to learn that the country is still heavily-resource dependent.

Comment: Alaska is likely a better State that models this.   Texas has some diversity to it's economy.

Comment: Correct, either way, I am just surprised that the recent literature frequently combines non-democratic and rentier states in one category, while it's possible to be a rentier state and resource-dependent like Norway or Alaska and still retain democratic elements in your system.

Comment: Are you asking about Norway (title) or about Texas (last para)? FWTW, Norway has higher oil income *per capita* than even Saudi Arabia. OTOH, I suspect they are more diversified than the Saudis.

Comment: There's also not a universally agreed method to define these notions https://academic.oup.com/wbro/article/36/2/164/5813434 In terms of oil *resources* (reserves) per capita Norway has way less that the Saudis.

Comment: Thanks, but why should we care about oil resources per capita? The question is merely whether Norway is a rentier state or not given that it shares common economic characteristics of classic rentier countries like Venezuela. In terms of employment and GDP shares, oil appears to play a crucial role in the country's economy.

Comment: Because you're talking about "mentality"?

Comment: Rentier mentality in the literature refers to the expectations that the government provides you with a cushy public sector job, it has nothing to do with oil resources per capita. See this decent paper: https://eprints.lse.ac.uk/103042/1/Steffen_Manuscript_Copyedited_SH_17_Dec_clean.pdf

Comment: @Fizz thanks for the really useful paper recommendation, will be reading it today!

Comment: "oil currently represents . . . 49% of total oil revenues" Did you mean government revenues?

Comment: The abstract of the paper you've linked speaks of "high per capita rents", so I'm not seeing how it's unrelated. Granted, resources per capita are more remotely connected, as they involve the future potential rather than mere present value of that "high per capita rents".

Comment: @ohwilleke Yes, correct.

Comment: For government income in Norway you have to take into account that quite a bit is squirelled away (not quite a scientific name) in the Oil Fund for later usage.

Comment: @ghellquist so what does that imply? Saudi Arabia and Kuwait both have similar funds since the 1950's btw. In fact, Kuwait's oil sovereign oil fund is the oldest state wealth fund in the world. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuwait_Investment_Authority

Comment: Why is this question tagged united-states?

Comment: @AgnishomChattopadhyay because some people mentioned Texas and Alaska as similar cases of a rentier central/regional government. For instance, Alaska has a similar cash distribution program as those typically studied in rentier countries. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alaska_Permanent_Fund

Comment: @AgnishomChattopadhyay The original version of the question suggested that Texas might be a rentier state. As the OP deleted that portion of the question, the united-states tag no longer applies.

Comment: I realize this is getting some traction here so the answer is maybe no, but given the technical nature of the question would this be a better fit for economics.SE?

Comment: No, the concept of rentier countries and resource-dependence has been a polsci literature before it became part of economics. The first mention of it and measuring has been done by political scientists, not economists.
See for instance Mahdavi, 1970 on the Iranian rentier state between 1950-1970.

Answer (score 7):

In my estimate, Norway is currently a rentier state (extracting signigicant revenue from the sale of natural resources) but **not** a resource-dependent country.

- Oil wealth and the sovereign savings fund it created boosts the standard of living. If you look at [GDP per capita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states_in_Europe_by_GDP_(PPP)_per_capita), Norway does better than Denmark, Sweden, or Finland.
- Norway has a sufficiently diverse economy, and a sufficiently stable democracy, that it *probably* could earn a similar per capita GDP to other nordic nations if oil was to disappear.

Comment: Norway gets 4.3% of its GDP from oil v. 32.2% Iraq, 31.9% D.R. of Congo, 24.0% for Angola, 19.4% for Oman, 17.7% for Saudi Arabia, 17.2% Iran, 11.7% for Qatar, 11.4% for Venezuela, 10.2% for Algeria, 1.1% for Canada. https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/NY.GDP.PETR.RT.ZS So, it is less rent dependent than many petro-states, but at the high end of the developed world.

Comment: @ohwilleke Not sure how oil rents are calculated in the WB data, but according to the Norway oil producing firm, the industry represents 33% of the country's GDP:
https://www.norskpetroleum.no/en/economy/governments-revenues/

Comment: @nesta1992: and if you apply the same estimation method as in the latter source to Saudi Arabia, you get what figure?

Comment: Good question, around 27.4% as of Q4, 2022. https://www.stats.gov.sa/sites/default/files/GDP%20Q042022E_1.pdf

Comment: @Fizz to be clear, I am not disputing that Saudi and Venezuela are not rentier states, I am just arguing that Norway appears similar to them across several economic indicators, esp those on the oil's contribution to the economy.

Comment: @nesta1992: what makes you so sure the Saudi  gov't uses the same estimation method as that Norwegian company? A quick search finds 46% from another source https://tradingeconomics.com/saudi-arabia/gdp-growth-oil-sector Or 42% from Moody's https://www.economy.com/saudi-arabia/indicators If you want to make comparisons, it's best to use the same source for the data.

Comment: More precisely, according to the latter, in SA: "The petroleum sector accounts for roughly 87% of budget revenues, 42% of GDP, and 90% of export earnings." For Norway: "12% of GDP, 13% of the state’s revenue, and 37% of exports, according to official national estimates". I suspect however there is a lot of variation from year-to-year, particularly in recent times.

Comment: @Fizz The data in both sources you provide is outdated. Not sure if you are aware, but Saudi Arabia has went through a drastic economic transformation in the past few years with some notable success, read the article below:
https://www.arabnews.com/node/2083841/business-economy

Comment: @nesta1992: quite possibly; see https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/79305/did-saudi-arabia-cut-in-half-its-oil-gas-share-of-gdp-from-2020-to-2022

Answer (score 3):

If we rely on the technical definition, than reliance on natural resources does not mean that the state should be non-democratic. One could perhaps argue that a non-democratic regime would have easier time staying in power, if it has an "easy" source of income, to calm the dissent among citizens by granting generous benefits. However, the same reasoning also explains the generous social policies and high level of government employment in Norway - the state spends money in order to make its citizens happy (though in a more accountable manner.)

Another thing to keep in mind is that comparing percentages is misleading when comparing countries of different size. Norway might have the same level of scientific and technological development as the US, and similar density of industry, while producing less oil than a single US state... and yet, the proportion would be very different. What could be a harsh verdict for a country with hundreds millions of people, is not so much of a problem in a country with population of 5 million.

Then, again, comparing to a place like Israel would draw a different picture again.

Answer (score 2):

Norway is clearly democratic, so linking it to a "rentier model" that postulates *bad governance due to resource reliance* seems somewhat of a stretch.

However, the [Dutch Disease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_disease) economic model that talks about over-reliance on resources and the effect on the wider economy seems a match.  This model, concerned about economics rather than governance, applies just fine to highly democratic countries, which need to mind its effects on their economies.

> In economics, the Dutch disease is the apparent causal relationship between the increase in the economic development of a specific sector (for example natural resources) and a decline in other sectors (like the manufacturing sector or agriculture).
>
> The term was coined in 1977 by The Economist to describe the decline of the manufacturing sector in the Netherlands after the discovery of the large Groningen natural gas field in 1959.[

Another way to look at this is also compare to the Tax-to-GDP ratio in Norway [to other economies](https://www.oecd.org/coronavirus/en/data-insights/tax-to-gdp-ratios).  Compared to other OECD countries, Norway's is not especially low.  However, it is quite a bit lower than the ratios of its Scandinavian peers which run similar social policies.

Note that, when discussing Norway's economy it is sometimes claimed that Norway was "poor until gas was discovered", which lends credence to Norway being a one trick pony.  However, that [claim is questionable](https://sciencenorway.no/economy-forskningno-norway/what-would-norway-be-like-without-oil-money/1442935).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response. I agree that it's an advanced and stable democracy, however, some macro indicators suggest that it might be relying too much on one source for revenues. After all, if oil represents 65% of a country's exports, I would argue that it's a reflection of some bad governance.
https://www.norskpetroleum.no/en/economy/governments-revenues/

Comment: @nesta1992: Why should a government want to hurt their exports *just* to lower an fairly arbitrary percentage? This answer points to a more fundamental reason, that looks beyond a single number.

Comment: @MSalters because we know from other historical examples like Netherlands and Venezuela, that relying on one source for gov't revenues and/or exports negatively changes the behavior of other producers/sectors in the private sector  throughout time. I recommend familiarizing yourself with the writings of Steffen Hertog, Michael Ross, and Luciani on the Dutch disease across different political contexts. Therefore, as a gov't, you should have an incentive to reduce (not hurt) your oil exports to avoid the disastrous consequences of the Dutch disease and a rentier mentality.

Answer (score 1):

Venezuela, Saudi Arabia, and Norway can all be called "rentier states", but the circumstances differ.

Venezuela came into its oil riches fairly early, in the 1910s and 1920s. Even before that, Venezuela was not a stable state, with the country alternating between left wing and right wing autocracies, occasional interspersed with democratically led governments. Instead of inspiring democracy, the country's oil wealth inspired those with aspirations of autocratic rule to take the reins.

Saudi Arabia came into its oil riches in the 1940s and 1950s. This was after the Saud family had already conquered almost all of the country and cemented their absolute monarchical rule. The discovery of massive oil deposits helped cement that rule even further. While there have been assassinations and rivalries, those have been intrafamily. The Saud family has partially ruled for over a century, and has ruled completely for over 50 years.

Norway came into its oil riches rather late, in the 1970s. By that time, Norway had already settled into being a fully democratic state with significant freedoms for the press and for individuals, and rights for those accused of crimes. All that the oil riches did was to make life easier for Norwegians. The killings, tortures, and inhumane treatments attributed to Venezuela and Saudi Arabia would be highly reported in Norway and not be tolerated there.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough and clear explanation. Is it fair to say that Norway and Indonesia are the only cases that are rentier and still able to retain democratic values despite their oil wealth?

Answer (score 0):

No. Norway is not a rentier state and being a democracy or not has nothing to do with it. In a rentier state a part of the population is employed in the exploitation on the commodity the state lives on and they are the only productive sector of the state. The rest of the population live off those revenues.

In Norway the [small population](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norway#Population) can only create a small alternative economy, the size of the [oil revenues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Norway_Product_Exports_(2019).svg) overshadows the rest. But that does not mean that the smaller component is not vital. Quite the opposite. The previous link shows that almost half of the exports are not related to oil. The overall [economy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norway#Economy) comprises a developed financial sector, hydroelectric, telecom and [ICT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economy_of_Greater_Oslo#ICT), tourism and other sectors.

Your misunderstanding may stem from the fact that lack of democracy also involves corruption. Corruption often creates an elite that does not produce anything, they just live off the resources produced by others. The size of that elite is determined by two opposing factors, the bigger it is the more stable their power is, but the higher is the damage on the country revenues. So a corrupt country can maintain a big elite only if they have very valuable resources, therefore only states that fit the definition of rentier states may fall in this group. But it is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks. The data source you provided on exports are outdated. The current 2023 figures show that 65% of exports come from oil, which represent 33% of the country's GDP. The oil revenues from 2022 were approximately 48% of the government budget. As mentioned in the post, if we rely on the technical definition from the literature, any country that relies on one resource for 40% or more of its revenues is a rentier state even it's democratic.

https://www.norskpetroleum.no/en/economy/governments-revenues/

Comment: @nesta1992 The figure of 65% was due to the spike in oil prices triggered by the war in Ukraine. This is something driven by the whole world economy and again it shows how a small country can see its real economy eclipsed by it. But on the other hand I think you misunderstand the definition of rentier country. Using a simple figure as a threshold to make the classification is a blunt oversimplification. In a rentier country the rest of the economy has no vitality, subpar productivity.

Comment: I am not the one using using a single figure to determine whether it's rentier or not, most prominent scholars on rentier states do, however. I suggest familiarizing yourself with the writings of Hertog, Michael Ross, Beblawi ,and Luciani.